# Run node script forever

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm writting an app which is waiting for message and then will do some action. Messages are receiving through the Redis channel. So, i need nodejs script to be running infinitely (as i understand)

How can i make it run without starting node server (i feel like it is wrong to start the server for such a simple task).

Code:

```
const redis = require("redis")
const subscriber = redis.createClient()
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3002;

subscriber.on("message", (channel, message) => {
  console.log(Buffer.from(message, 'base64'));
})

subscriber.subscribe('test')

// Server code, which i was using to start infinity loop
//
// const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
//   res.statusCode = 200;
//   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
//   res.end('Hello World\n');
// });
//
// server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
//   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
// });
```

Comment: So you want the node server to be running with it being running?

Comment: A node process will stay running as long as there is an open socket connection, a listening server or a waiting timer.  If your app doesn't have at least one of those, then it's unlikely it can really do anything anyway.  If your redis channel subscription is a connection to some other server process, then your node app should keep running as long as you have that connection.

Answer (score 0):

**subscriber.js**

> ```
> const redis = require("redis");
> const subscriber = redis.createClient();
> const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
> const port = 6379;
> subscriber.on("message", function(channel, message) {
>     console.log(message);
> });
> subscriber.subscribe('test');
> ```

**publisher.js**

> ```
> const redis = require("redis");
> const publisher = redis.createClient();
> const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
> const port = 6379;
>
> publisher.publish('test',"Hello I am Here !!!");
> ```

This is an Example Code for both publisher and subscriber.No need to run an HTTP server to subscribe from redis. You just want to keep run subscriber.js .

If this channel is inactive for a particular day channel goes to sleep state.So all other messages are may be lost.

If you want to avoid this,you need to run a scheduler script to publish a dummy message to your channel for particular day (May be per day once)

You can use *forever npm module* to run your node continuously.

Comment: hostname and port variables are unnecessary in your code and in your case it'll just execute once.